# Questions which can be answered by framework documentation

Tags: discussion

Just a simple questions: What should I do with questions, which can be answered by the frameworks documentation?

Somebody asked [what does deviceready event in cordova really do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692543/what-does-deviceready-event-in-cordova-really-do) and this topic is already well explained inside the documentation. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Should I flag this question? If yes, with what flag?

Comment: Post an link to the documentation, with a good relevant excerpt. If the topic is too broad for that, flag it as too broad.

Comment: If the right part of the docs is easily found, also downvote for lack of research.